# Checkbox doesn't read from settings correctly

Tags: c#, checkbox, settings

Here's the issue:

In my Settings I have two boolean called "check1_State" and "check2_State". They are supposed to control my two checkboxes whenever the form loads.

Here's the code for when the Form loads:

```
checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.check1_State;
checkBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.check2_State;
```

With that piece of code, only checkBox1 will be read. If I comment the first line, the second one will work just fine.

I managed to get it to work for putting a Timer whenever the form loads, but I wanted to do it the right. That shows that the checkboxes can, in fact, read from the settings, but apparently it doesn't work if two or more are requested at the same time.

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Are you writing the settings in the check changed event handler?

Comment: I am. Then again, it works fine if the .Checked = .check1_State; is used in a timer, it just does not work if it is input into the Form.Load handler.

Comment: Place a debugged on checkBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.check2_State; and see if the state is set properly or not. If it is set properly then you should register the checked change event of checkbox2. To see where it is changed from after you have set it. I suspect it is changed somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have form level flag for keep state of loading initial data

```
bool flag = false;
```

Save `check1_State` and `check2_State` **only** if above flag is **`true`**

in form load event, set the flag after loading data from properties

```
checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.check1_State;
checkBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.check2_State;
flag = true;
```

sample :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool flag = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            //save settings 
        }
    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            //save settings 
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.check1_State;
        checkBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.check2_State;
        flag = true;
    }
}
```